# Issue with local cocoa pods path

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm trying to set the path of a library locally since i don't want it to be updating all the time when i run pod install. I've saw you can use the path variable to set the path of the folder but this isn't working when i set the path to the folder.

The pod is setup like this:

```
 pod 'Spring', :path => '/Users/xxxxxxxx/project-name/Project/App/xcode-project-name/Spring'
```

The error I keep on getting is the following:

```
[!] No podspec found for `Spring` in `/Users/xxxxxxxx/project-name/Project/App/xcode-project-name/Spring`
```

Also to mention the Xcode-project-name does have a space in it i'm not too sure if this would affect anything?

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue with a local pod once. My directory had *spaces* and I was escaping it correctly

Problem is that I needed to use **Double quotes** instead of single quotes. The working solution was:

```
pod 'MyPod', :path =>  "/Users/honey/Desktop/cool\ group\ /Repos/coolPod"
```

In the few languages I know wrapping in single quotes would not interpret the passed string while wrapping in double quotes does

Answer (score 0):

Yes the space can cause a problem, to test is go to terminal and `cd` to your path

```
cd  /Users/xxxxxxxx/project-name/Project/App/xcode-project-name/Spring
```

If it throws error then you must use correct path.

When giving path the spaces are escaped using `\` character. e.g.

If your path is `/Users/My Xcode Projects` the this path is `/Users/My\ Xcode\ Projects`

Before messing around the paths do consider [Michael Dautermann's answer on your post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33063395/468724)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of futzing around with paths and worrying about whether something is going to be updated or not, why not simply freeze the Pod version of "`Spring`" that you are working with.

That is, in your Podspec:

```
pod 'Spring', '1.0.3'
```

That way, you won't pick up the newest version of Spring every time you do a "`pod install`".

More information can be seen under ["Specifying pod versions" section in the Cocoapods guide](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html).

Comment: Well i've edited the source code and if i do that it would remove all the changes that i've made

Comment: I've edited code in one of my local pods also.  For stuff like that, I simply *removed* the Pod from the PodSpec and [download a local copy of the source to include it in my project outside of the Pods target.

Comment: I think this is probably the thing to do thanks for that :)